# Postgres append or set each elements(if not exists) of an array to an array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

If I have

```
select arr_str from tabl1;
-> {'a', 'b'}
```

then how do I add this `{'b','c','d'}` array to column `arr_str`
so that I would get the following result

```
select arr_str from tabl1;
-> {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
```

I don't want to **SELECT** the column and create a new array for updating. I only want to use **UPDATE** query.

Comment: There is chance that `arr_str` may contains duplicate values ?

Comment: **arr_str** can hold duplicate values but I dont want to add duplicate values

Comment: Updated the question... Only want to use **update** query

Comment: but you need keep that source duplicate values ?

Comment: if `arr_str` holds `{'a', 'b', 'b'}` and you want add `{'b','c','d'}`, what will expected array from this ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'll assume that `arr_str` is of type `text[]` (although you did not use the proper format for them, so I may be wrong; if that's the case, you'll need to cast your value to `text[]`).

Use the following statement, if you want to remove duplications, which are already present in the `arr_str` column:

```
update tabl1
set    arr_str = (select array_agg(distinct e) from unnest(arr_str || '{b,c,d}') e)
where arr_str is null or not arr_str @> '{b,c,d}'
```

Or, use the following one when you want to preserve existing duplications:

```
update tabl1
set    arr_str = arr_str || array(select unnest('{b,c,d}'::text[]) except select unnest(arr_str))
where  not arr_str @> '{b,c,d}'
```

Both of these statements won't touch rows, which won't be affected anyway (look at the `where not arr_str @> '{b,c,d}'` predicate). This is usualy the best practice, and is almost always recommended, when triggers are involved.

http://rextester.com/GKS7382

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the perfect reply/answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: Does not append to rows with arr_str as NULL

Comment: @ShubhamGupta no operations append anything to NULLs. That's kind of the point, as NULL is not an empty array, but rather an unknown array. If you use it for empty arrays, you'll have to use `coalesce(arr_str, '{}')` in WHEREs and the right hand side of SETs manually.

Answer (score 17):

With default pg install you can merge two arrays with || operator:

```
select arr_str || '{a, b}' from tabl1
```

But in that case you will get duplicates.

To avoid them, you can unnest array into rowset and distinct it:

```
select ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT UNNEST(arr_str || '{a,b,c}')) from tabl1
```

If your values are integers, there is more elegant way to get uniq array values with intarray contrib module and uniq() function:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html

You can add these integer array functions by using:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION intarray
```

Comment: Great explanation, this helped me get back on track!

Answer (score 1):

you can [concatenate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) arrays and then aggregate distinct values:

```
t=# with a as (select unnest('{a, b}'::text[] || '{b,c,d}'::text[]) a) select array_agg(distinct a) from a;
 array_agg
-----------
 {a,b,c,d}
(1 row)

Time: 1.312 ms
```

Comment: Yes, but I actually wanted to UPDATE the column itself. I dont want to SELECT the column and create a new array for updating before doing UPDATE to the column. I only want to use UPDATE query.

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the question. Please update

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
select array(select distinct unnest(string_to_array('a,b',',') || string_to_array('b,c,d',',')) order by 1)
```

Comment: Yes, but I actually wanted to UPDATE the column itself. I dont want to SELECT the column and create a new array for updating before doing UPDATE to the column. I only want to use UPDATE query.